# Can't install packages due to dpkg error, common solution fails

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

Most solutions to correct this behaviour does not work.

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge paper-icon-theme
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
~$ sudo apt-get remove paper-icon-theme
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
~$  sudo apt-get install -f
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` hangs the system. Tried it for more than 1 hour, system was just as unresponsive as it was when the command was immediately run.

That command is not working. It just hangs the minute it runs.

Error occurred when one day I was installing a paper-icon-theme and the power accidentaly lost. Since then I am not able to run the `apt-get install` command.

What do I do?

On Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo dpkg -D2000 --configure -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot to the GRUB menu.
- Choose "**Advanced options for Ubuntu**".
- Now choose the first / top-most "(**recovery mode**)" option.
- Now you will be shown a "**Recovery Menu**". From here, choose the "**root access**" option.
- Enter your root password when prompted.

Run these commands:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
fsck -f /
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should do it.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it worked / helped, if you have any further issues, feel free to post and I am confident someone will help  you.